# Showing Tooltipster Tip With Both Focus & Hover

Tags: javascript, jquery, tooltipster

We are utilizing the tooltipster plugin to display a tooltip over an info icon.   This works fine on hover.   But we also need to have it show if someone tabs to the info icon too.

I can't seem to find any examples of how to enable the popup on both hover AND focus.

This is what existed in this project already:

**HTML:**

```
<a href="#"><span class="tooltip">Some handy tooltip text...</span></a>
```

**Javascript:**

```
if ($('.tooltip').length) {
        $('.tooltip').tooltipster({
            theme: '.tooltipster-shadow',
            maxWidth: 220,
            interactive: true,
            functionReady: function () {
                $('html').click(function () {
                    $.fn.tooltipster('hide');
                });
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: No need for the `if` block. jQuery handles that for you.

Comment: Removing the `if` block doesn't solve the problem.  :-)

Comment: Wasn't suggesting that it would. Just trying to save you many lines of code down the trail. Otherwise I'd have made it an answer. ;-)

Comment: For newer versions of Tooltipster look at the docs here http://calebjacob.github.io/tooltipster/#triggers. You can have multiple triggers for open or close, i.e. mouseenter and tap.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use Tooltipster's show method like so:

```
$('.tooltip').tooltipster().focus(function() {
    $(this).tooltipster('show');
});
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/gcLutcas/)**

http://iamceege.github.io/tooltipster/#advanced

Comment: Adding this causes the tooltip to not appear at all (on hover or click).

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for that :

```
$('.tooltip_hover_n_click').tooltipster({
  delay: 100,
  trigger: 'custom' // disable all by default
}).mouseover(function(){ // show on hover
  $(this).tooltipster('show');
}).blur(function(){ // on click it'll focuses, and will hide only on blur
  $(this).tooltipster('hide');
}).mouseout(function(){ // if user doesnt click, will hide on mouseout
  if(document.activeElement !== this){
    $(this).tooltipster('hide');
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 $('.tooltip').tooltipster({
            theme: '.tooltipster-shadow',
            trigger: 'custom',
            maxWidth: 220,
            interactive: true,
            functionReady: function () {
                $('html').click(function () {
                    $.fn.tooltipster('hide');
                });
            }.on( 'focus, hover', function() {
               $( this ).tooltipster( 'show' );
            }).on( 'focusout, mouseout', function() {
               $( this ).tooltipster( 'hide' );
            })
        });
```